# Screen command and python

Tags: python, linux

I want to run a process (a python program) on a remote machine. I have both Canopy and Anaconda installed.

After I SSH into the remote machine, if I type 'python', I get the python prompt - the Canopy version.

If I type 'screen', hit 'enter', then type 'python', I get the python prompt - the Anaconda version.

I want to use the Canopy version when I'm in 'screen'. How can I do so?

Comment: find full path to Canony python `which python` and later use this full path in screen.

Comment: Thank you, but this does not solve the problem.
I type 'which python', and I get the path. If I type 'screen /path/to/Canopy', then I just get an active python session using Canopy. I would like to use my Canopy version to run a separate python program. I would like to type 'python program.py' and have it run from the Canopy version.

Comment: I was thinking about `/path/to/Canopy/python` or  `/path/to/Canopy/python script.py` but I see you found this solution :). Maybe somewhere in screen configuration (or Bash configuration `.bashrc`) you could set `alias python=/path/to/Canopy/python` or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! Here's how:

1) In terminal, after SSHing into the remote machine, type 'which python' (thanks @furas!). This gives path/to/Canopy/python

2) In terminal, type 'screen path/to/Canopy/python program.py' to run the desired program (called program.py) in the Canopy version of python.

Answer (score 2):

To get the same environment with screen that you got when you logged in, create a .screenrc file in your home directory or add to an existing one, with a line

```
shell -/bin/bash
```

Exit out of all other screen sessions so that `screen -ls` shows nothing.

Restart screen by just typing `screen` and see if that fixes it.